# Why ItemsControl.ToolTip is visible only if mouse over its item

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip, mouseover, itemscontrol

Here the problem. I have an **ItemsControl**, and I want to show a **ToolTip** if user hover mouse over **ItemsControl**. Seems easy, right?

Here an example:

```
<ItemsControl BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1">
    <ItemsControl.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="Text" />
    </ItemsControl.ToolTip>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <Label BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">One</Label>
    <Label BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">Two</Label>
    <Label BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">Three</Label>
    <Label BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">Four</Label>
    <Label BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">Five</Label>
    <Label BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">Six</Label>
    <Label BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">Seven</Label>
</ItemsControl>
```

Make window width small enough, and let **WrapPanel** to wrap an items. And try to hover over **ItemsControl** (**ToolTip** will not appears), than hover over **Label** (**ToolTip** will appears).

Why this behavior is right and how to force **ToolTip** to appears in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ToolTip` for `ItemsControl` doesn't show in any case until you give the `Background` a `Brush`.

```
<ItemsControl Background="Transparent"
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with hovering over a grid in an ItemsControl. It appears that unless you set the Background on a control then the mouse hover falls through if you aren't over a child element.